# How do I use .drop() to drop the first line in a csv file?

Tags: scala, csv

So in scala I am using this to iterate over my lines from the csv file:

```
for (line <- Source.fromFile(file).getLines) {
}
```

If I changed it to:

```
for (line <- Source.fromFile(file).getLines.drop(1)) {
}
```

Would this drop the entire first line or just drop the first element on the first line? My first line of my csv file is filled with headers. It looks like this

```
Birthday,Zip Code,Name,City,State,Country
```

And after the header there are thousands of lines of entry, I just don't want the first line included when I read this and put it into an array or Seq.

Comment: `.drop(n)` selects all sequence elements except first _n_ ones. So you need to answer question what is element of the sequence returned by `getLines`?

Comment: Why not just write a small test and see by yourself? ;)

Comment: @GuruStron ahh get line returns an entire line so saying drop(1) should drop the entire line